# Resetting Terraform state config

Tags: terraform

On a few occasions lately since I have started working with remote state, I have incorrectly configured my state by specifying the wrong value in my backend config.  Once I run terraform init with this incorrect info and the it throws an error...even after I correct the error I am unable to properly configure the backend.  I "think" what is happening is when I run init with the bad information, it is written to terraform.state in the .terraform folder.  When I then correct the error and re-run terraform init, it sees my correction as a change, tries to verify the old config (which is bad) before changing to the new config but fails because it can't verify the old.  The only way I know around this right now is to delete the .terraform folder and then running terraform init again with the right info.

Am I misunderstanding what is going on and is there a better way around this problem?

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail to get an answer here. Terraform backend config recognises changes and has interactive and programmatic functions used for reconfiguring and migrating state when a change is detected. Your issue sounds like that’s not happening. See backend configuration: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/init.html